# How to make a static site look dynamic - .htaccess in apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, web

I have a site that I am running in Apache that is static and I want the server to treat each file as a directory. I have this thing set up in .htaccess that will get rid of all .html extensions. So this is what I want:

Ex.

http://example.com/about (Currently)

to

http://example.com/about/

without having to change it into a directory or make it dynamic. Is there a .htaccess **hack**? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out mod_rewrite which lets you rewrite any url using regular expressions.